# Split Line by Partially Known Delimiter

Tags: java, xml, split, delimiter

I have a String like this:

```
String xml = "<Tag1>Tag One<Tag1><Tag2>Tag Two<Tag2><Fhfuehwalifhre>Bla Bla<Fhfuehwalifhre>"
```

I want to split this line (without knowing the names of the tags) so that I get a String array like this:

```
["Tag One"], ["Tag Two"], ["Bla Bla"]
```

Is there a way to go about doing this in a single line?  (Such as `xml.split("<*>");`, but that does not work.)  Or do I need to do it the ugly way and split it by `<` and `>` and then weed out the undesireables?

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You've called your string `xml`.  If it's XML, this is very brittle. What happens if elements are nested?,  What if there are self closing elements?

Comment: It is just a string name. It can be called ZML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "\<[^\>]+\>" in the split

Comment: hmmm...that does not compile. weird

Comment: Do `<` and `>` have to be escaped? I don't think they have any meaning in java patterns.

Comment: you should use \\<[^\\>]+\\>  ... but it give 6 results 3 empty strings.

Comment: Hovav and Banthar thanks guys! it works if i dont escape < and >.  I can green checkmark in 5 minutes. please correct answer to exclude the \'s. Hovav

Comment: String[] answer = xml.split("<[^>]+>"); works, but as @pL4Gu33 says, it gives some extra empty elements.  No need for any of the \'s